# Continous animation to show or hide element without fade

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to continuously show and hide two page elements in turn.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var continuous = function () {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#Mass_alert").css('display','block'); $("#Devotion_alert").css('display','none'); },1500);
    setTimeout(function() { $("#Mass_alert").css('display','none'); $("#Devotion_alert").css('display','block'); },1500);
    };
    setInterval(continuous,500); 
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
  <div id="Mass_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px;">Mass alert</div>
  <div id="Devotion_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px;">devotion alert</div>
```

I get the right effect once. What should I change in the code above to have the continuous effect.  I don't want to use fadeToggle, because, I actually need the `display:none` setting.  If I don't then there is space left for the hidden element that interferes with the placement of the other element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $('#Mass_alert, #Devotion_alert').toggle();
}, 1500);
```

​
with:

```
<div id="Mass_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px;">Mass alert</div>
<div id="Devotion_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px; display: none;">devotion alert</div>​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxMdA/1/

Comment: Is there a way to add a fade animation to that toggle?

Comment: @user823527 you could use `fadeToggle`, though this looks strange, `slideToggle` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try just toggling back and forth.

```
var a = false;
$(document).ready(toggle);
function toggle() {
    if (a) {
        $("#Mass_alert").css('display','block'); $("#Devotion_alert").css('display','none'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Mass_alert").css('display','none'); $("#Devotion_alert").css('display','block'); 
    }

    a = !a;

    setTimeout(toggle, 1500);
}
```